# c++ get byte equivalent of function and execute

Tags: c++

How would i take a function, for example `void example() { int i = 1; }` and convert it into it's byte equivalent? So something like this (for an example):

```
0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42
```

And then take these bytes and execute them as if they were the original function `void example() { int i = 1; }`. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you want to develop a compiler and CPU (existance or byte-code you designed) emulator? It should be possible with a lot of effort.

Comment: Your sample function would be most probably emitted as a NOP.

Comment: This is exactly what your compiler does

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one that's being asked here, but the problem for which you believe the answer is what's being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge this byte method won't work

U could possible get the address of the function and store the same in a function pointer 
And execute the function by calling the function pointer

Try searching for function pointer